# Como creo un script en nodeJS para hacer backup de mi base de datos en postgres

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo que crear un script con nodeJS para poder hacer un backup de mi base de datos, ya he buscado bastante, se que con pgdump pero el problema lo tengo es a la hora de hacer el script ya que no se como iniciar realmente..

Comment: ¿Por qué no hacer un script de consola (fichero sh o bat), directamente?

Comment: si estuve viendo esa posibilidad, pero me dicen que tengo que crearla en la api...

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar el módulo `child_process`:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('pgdump PON EL RESTO DE PARAMETROS', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```